# Python issubset performance comparing with finding element in set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing a programming exercise on Leetcode (500 Keyboard Row) and I came across set.issubset() in discussions. Upon comparing with my own answer, here's an interesting finding:

1)

```
def checkWord(self, word):
    r1 = 'qwertyuiop'
    r2 = 'asdfghjkl'
    r3 = 'zxcvbnm'
    row = 0
    for idx, ch in enumerate(word):
        if idx == 0:
            row = 1 if ch in r1 else 2 if ch in r2 else 3
            continue
        coming_row = 1 if ch in r1 else 2 if ch in r2 else 3
        if row != coming_row:
            return False
    return True
```

If I submit with this, I get a runtime of 40ms

2)

```
def checkWord(self, word):
    r1 = 'qwertyuiop'
    r2 = 'asdfghjkl'
    r3 = 'zxcvbnm'
    return set(word).issubset(r1) or set(word).issubset(r2) or set(word).issubset(r3)
```

If I use issubset(), I get a runtime of 36ms, which beats 94.87% of all submissions.

3) So I thought, hmmm, what's the difference with this piece? According to a question I found on this topic [The complextiy of Python issubset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674289/the-complextiy-of-python-issubset), the time complexity of method 2) should be O(len(word)), which I believe should be the same with this piece:

```
def checkWord(self, word):
    r1 = set('qwertyuiop')
    r2 = set('asdfghjkl')
    r3 = set('zxcvbnm')
    row = 0
    for idx, ch in enumerate(word):
        if idx == 0:
            row = 1 if ch in r1 else 2 if ch in r2 else 3
            continue
        coming_row = 1 if ch in r1 else 2 if ch in r2 else 3
        if row != coming_row:
            return False
    return True
```

However, the runtime of this is 32ms and beats 100% of all py3 submissions... Why is issubset() slower than this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your first version of `checkWord` function doesn't check if `ch` value is in `r3` set, so you avoid one check.

Furthermore, in your second version of `checkword` you create a set with the `word` parameter's characters **three** times. Why don't you store the set before checking with 'issubset'? Your code will be something like this:

```
def checkWord3(word):
    r1 = 'qwertyuiop'
    r2 = 'asdfghjkl'
    r3 = 'zxcvbnm'
    s1 = set(word)
    return s1.issubset(r1) or s1.issubset(r2) or s1.issubset(r3)
```

This is another solution using regular expressions:

```
r1 = re.compile("^[qwertyuiop]+$")
r2 = re.compile("^[asdfghjkl]+$")
r3 = re.compile("^[zxcvbnm]+$")

r1.match(word) or r2.match(word) or r3.match(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following methods:

```
import random
import string

def checkWord1(word):
    r1 = 'qwertyuiop'
    r2 = 'asdfghjkl'
    r3 = 'zxcvbnm'
    row = 0
    for idx, ch in enumerate(word):
        if idx == 0:
            row = 1 if ch in r1 else 2 if ch in r2 else 3
            continue
        coming_row = 1 if ch in r1 else 2 if ch in r2 else 3
        if row != coming_row:
            return False
    return True

def checkWord2(word):
    r1 = 'qwertyuiop'
    r2 = 'asdfghjkl'
    r3 = 'zxcvbnm'
    return set(word).issubset(r1) or set(word).issubset(r2) or set(word).issubset(r3)

def checkWord3(word):
    r1 = 'qwertyuiop'
    r2 = 'asdfghjkl'
    r3 = 'zxcvbnm'
    r = set(word)
    return r.issubset(r1) or r.issubset(r2) or r.issubset(r3)

def checkWord4(word):
    r1 = set('qwertyuiop')
    r2 = set('asdfghjkl')
    r3 = set('zxcvbnm')
    row = 0
    for idx, ch in enumerate(word):
        if idx == 0:
            row = 1 if ch in r1 else 2 if ch in r2 else 3
            continue
        coming_row = 1 if ch in r1 else 2 if ch in r2 else 3
        if row != coming_row:
            return False
    return True
```

And measure execution time:

```
word = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(0, 9)))

print("One:")
%timeit -n 10000 checkWord1(word)
print("Two:")
%timeit -n 10000 checkWord2(word)
print("Three:")
%timeit -n 10000 checkWord3(word)
print("Four:")
%timeit -n 10000 checkWord4(word)
```

Get results:

```
One:
475 ns ± 88.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Two:
708 ns ± 117 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Three:
552 ns ± 19.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Four:
1.19 µs ± 10.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Although with different randomly generated string, the results are similar.

One is fastest, Three is faster and more stable than Two, Four is worst.

The reason I think why One is fastest is that

1. `issubset(object)` actually implicitly convert `object` to a `set`. That is costly.
2. This comparison is unfair. Suppose we have one word `"qsdfwe"`, in method One, it will be check if in `r1`, and in the following loop, if it is found not a sub set of `r1`, there is also no possibility that it can be a sub set of others.

So I implement a even faster method, I think we can just focus on one row which is decided by the first char as these three rows are exclusive so that we do not check others any more.

```
def checkWord5(word):
    r = ['qwertyuiop', 'asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm']
    first_char = word[0]
    row = r[0] if first_char in r[0] else r[1] if first_char in r[1] else r[2]
    for ch in word[1:]:
        if ch not in row:
            return False
    return True
```

Get results:

```
One:
728 ns ± 236 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Two:
2.08 µs ± 55.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Three:
1.43 µs ± 60 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Four:
1.45 µs ± 7.74 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Five:
374 ns ± 7.01 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Great comparison! Thanks!